# Isotope: Fade in Filters on Item Select?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I'm not sure how this would be done at all, so thought I would ask here.

I'm trying to use Isotope for body part instructions, but I have way to many filter options on the page. Heres the code:

```
<ul id="options" class="combo-filters ">
<li class="level-1 parent-active first">
<a href="/instructions/">Body Part</a>
<div class="option-combo bodypart">
<ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="bodypart"> 
<li><a href="#filter-bodypart-all" data-filter-value="" class="selected">all</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-bodypart-chest" data-filter-value=".chest">Chest</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-bodypart-legs" data-filter-value=".legs">Legs</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-bodypart-back" data-filter-value=".back">Back</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-bodypart-shoulders" data-filter-value=".shoulders">Shoulders</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-bodypart-arms" data-filter-value=".arms">Arms</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="option-combo goal">
<a href="/instructions/">Goal</a>
<ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="goal"> 
<li><a href="#filter-goal-all" data-filter-value="" class="selected">all</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-goal-mass" data-filter-value=".mass">mass</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-goal-shaping" data-filter-value=".shaping">shaping</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="option-combo focusarea">


<a href="/instructions/">Chest</a>
<ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="focusarea"> 
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-all" data-filter-value="" class="selected">all</a></li>

<!-- Chest -->
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-upper" data-filter-value=".upper">upper</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-middle" data-filter-value=".middle">middle</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-lower" data-filter-value=".lower">lower</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="/instructions/">Back</a>
<ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="focusarea"> 
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-all" data-filter-value="" class="selected">all</a></li>

<!-- Back -->
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-width" data-filter-value=".width">width</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-thickness" data-filter-value=".thickness">thickness</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-lowerback" data-filter-value=".lowerback">lower back</a></li>
</ul>


<a href="/instructions/">Shoulders</a>
<ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="focusarea"> 
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-all" data-filter-value="" class="selected">all</a></li>
<!-- Shoulders -->
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-sidedelt" data-filter-value=".sidedelt">side delt</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-rearposteriordelt" data-filter-value=".rearposteriordelt">rear posterior delt</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-traps" data-filter-value=".traps">traps</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-allshoulderheads" data-filter-value=".allshoulderheads">all shoulder heads</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-anteriorfrontdelt" data-filter-value=".anteriorfrontdelt">anterior front delt</a></li>
</ul>

<a href="/instructions/">Legs</a>
<ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="focusarea"> 
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-all" data-filter-value="" class="selected">all</a></li>


<!-- Legs -->
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-glutes" data-filter-value=".glutes">glutes</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-calves" data-filter-value=".calves">calves</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-thighs" data-filter-value=".thighs">thighs</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-hamstrings" data-filter-value=".hamstrings">hamstrings</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-quads" data-filter-value=".quads">quads</a></li>

</ul>


<a href="/instructions/">Arms</a>
<ul class="filter option-set clearfix " data-filter-group="focusarea"> 
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-all" data-filter-value="" class="selected">all</a></li>

<!-- Arms -->
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-biceps" data-filter-value=".biceps">biceps</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-triceps" data-filter-value=".triceps">triceps</a></li>
<li><a href="#filter-focusarea-forearms" data-filter-value=".forearms">forearms</a></li>


</ul>

</div>
</li>

</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is only display "Body Part" and "Goal", and if "Chest" under body part is selected, it will fade in the "Chest" focus area which loads the "All, Upper, Middle, Lower" options.

Whats the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See complex filtering in the [plugin author's documentation here](http://support.metafizzy.co/2012/combo-filter-checkboxes.html) and examine it in Chrome's devtools panel.

Comment: I dont understand, how does this work with what im trying to do?

Comment: From the insufficient description without jsfiddle or link to your sandbox, it seemed you are after cascading filter options. Never mind.